# How to style print window's table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to print the grid html table by clicking the 'print' button so when I printing by below javascript code, Getting simple rows and columns table, How to style print window's table? 
I have tried like below,

```
function printData() {        
        var myDiv = document.getElementById('tablerecords');
        var newWindow = window.open('', 'SecondWindow', 'toolbar=0,stat=0');//
        var style = newWindow.document.createElement('link');
        style.type = "text/css";
        style.rel = "stylesheet";
        style.href = "~/Styles/PrintTableStyle.css";
        style.media = "all";
        newWindow.document.write("<html><body "+
            " önload='window.print()'>" +
            myDiv.outerHTML +
            "</body></html>");
        newWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(style);
        newWindow.print();
        newWindow.document.close();
    }
```

and styling for print window's table is below

```
#tablerecords {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

    #tablerecords td, #tablerecords th {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 8px;
    }

    #tablerecords tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }

    #tablerecords tr:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    #tablerecords th {
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        text-align: left;
        background-color: Black;
        color: white;
    }
```

Comment: To start, I don't believe the tilde (`~`) can work in this context. It's not being processed by anything (i.e. ASP). Use an absolute (`/`) or relative (`../`) path. Also, to make this process even simpler, I'd suggest using the [@media print](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#Examples) CSS query on the same page instead of opening a new window with JavaScript. Much easier to style and debug. You can then call `window.print()` to apply these styles.

Comment: `" önload='window.print()'>" +` in the 10th line is a typo for `" onload='window.print()'>" +`? Note the `o` of `onload`

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! An important concept in Stack Overflow, is to produce a [*minimal, complete, and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. This ensures your code is in its simplest form so more focus can go to that actual issue, rather than having to dig through your code to find it. And 99% of the time, once you have created this minimal code, you will have answered your own problem. In the future be sure to remove any part of your code that isn't necessary to reproduce the issue. Good Luck!

Comment: @Sheng Slogar where to use that media? can you please syntax it

Comment: @abbasahmed Check the link I included in my comment, it contains a full working example. The media query would be placed at root level in your CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my self by opening print window in same page. and also solved the actions column hiding in print window and preventing the failure of 2nd click of print button by reloading current window, below is my code.

```
function printData() {
        var divElements = document.getElementById('tablerecords').outerHTML;
        var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>" + 
        divElements + "</body>";
        $("#tablerecords th:last-child, #tablerecords td:last-child").hide();
        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;
        location.reload();
    }
```